# jquery-bootstrap4Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I get this error when I write jQuery code. How can I fix it

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

I am trying to using jQuery to validate the form. Everything is ok but I get 
this error.

```js
$('#err-text-p').hide();

function passwordEvent() {
  if ($(this.target).val().length > 8) {
    $('#err-text-p').hide();
  } else {
    $('#err-text-p').show();
  }
}

$('#md-inpt5').focus(passwordEvent).keyup(passwordEvent);
```

Comment: Use either `$(this)` or the `target` property of the event which is passed to the function. `this` does not have a `target` property

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to a access the element in the focus event.  Try using $(this).val() rather than $(this.target).val().  Also verify that the val is defined

```
$('#err-text-p').hide();

function passwordEvent() {
  if ($(this).val() && $(this).val().length > 8) {
    $('#err-text-p').hide();
  } else {
    $('#err-text-p').show();
  }
}

$('#md-inpt5').focus(passwordEvent).keyup(passwordEvent);
```